# Using cancelto in the cancel package but the arrow is wavy not straight

Tags: cancel

I used the `cancel` package today for the first time but the arrow isn't straight. Is this normal?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  L\{2\cos(3t)\}(s)
   & = 2\int_0^{\infty}\cos(3t)e^{-st}dt\\
   & = \cancelto{0}{\frac{2e^{-st}\sin(3t)}{3}\biggl|_0^{\infty}} +
   \frac{s}{3}\int_0^{\infty}\sin(3t)e^{-st}dt
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to use this package, but at the same time, it is sloppy unless there is a fix for this problem.

Comment: How do you mean arrow is not straight?

Comment: @percusse look at the arrow. It definitely isn't a nice straight line no matter the zoom so it isn't an artifact of the pdf viewer which occurs with some instances of LaTeX but disappear when you adjust the zoom.

Comment: Ah you mean rasterized or pixallated. Got it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it should be fine now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cancel` uses picture environment commands, so sloping lines are made by positioning many font glyphs with small line segments, this inevitably gives a notch sometimes as rounding error moves the line from one pixel to the next.

Normally in such cases, you can use

```
\usepackage{pict2e}
```

to re-implement the picture mode commands using pdf drawing primitives to get a smoother appearance and less restrictions on available slopes.

That didn't work here, but it turns out that's a documented feature, the end of `cancel.sty` says

```
% pict2e removes bounding box from line and vector, so use original
% versions by declaring \OriginalPictureCmds; make it a no-op if undefined

\@ifundefined{OriginalPictureCmds}{\let\OriginalPictureCmds\relax}{}

% Sometime maybe find a better solution that uses all slopes with pict2e
```

So currently that's just how it is.