# Cancel package enhancement

Tags: math-mode, formatting, cancel

How difficult is it to enhance (=copy the code of the package in my project and adapt it) the Cancel package,
[Cancel package](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.sty), with a command `\cancelno{〈label〉}{〈expression〉}` such that

- a slash is put on the underlying `〈expression〉` as by `\cancel`
- no arrow
- the number/text `〈label〉` is put on top of `〈expression〉` in the middle

the **goal** is to describe which term cancel with which term, this is useful if one has lets say 16 terms each cancelling with each other.

I think that the command `\cancelto` of the package should be a good model.

In the following MEW one should replace `\cancelto` with `\cancelno` and obtain the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}

\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right)
\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}bz-cy\\cx-az\\ay-bx\end{bmatrix}
\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\cancelto{1}{bza}-\cancelto{2}{cya}+\cancelto{3}{cxb}
-\cancelto{1}{azb}+\cancelto{2}{ayc}-\cancelto{3}{bxc}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14385/138900 are you agree with that ?

Comment: These question is too a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218372/138900 are you agree with that ?

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234535/138900

Comment: @AndréC The other question is about changing the format of the arrow (downwards instead of upwards) in case of expression that are replaced by a value. This question in another concept: I want to visualize which terms get canceled with which terms (that is, a grouping of the terms that cancel with each other)

Comment: @AndréC also the other two have to do with layout and not with meaning. The arrow in my case would be misleading since I want to group the terms and not replace them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably it is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\mycancel}[2]{\overset{#1}{\cancel{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}

\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right)
\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}bz-cy\\cx-az\\ay-bx\end{bmatrix}
\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\mycancel{1}{bza}-\mycancel{2}{cya}+\mycancel{3}{cxb}
-\mycancel{1}{azb}+\mycancel{2}{ayc}-\mycancel{3}{bxc}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: possible and even that simple! thank you

Comment: Are you a schrodinger's marmot?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer So you want to know why Schrödinger's equation was written down/invented in an Alpine hut? I think mankind is not yet ready for that.