# `cancelto` : choppy arrow problem

Tags: formatting, arrows, draw, cancel

I am using the package `cancel` to do the operation as shown in figure. 
[image: pic]

As you can see the arrow is choppy. I read another question mentioning the same error : [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234535/using-cancelto-in-the-cancel-package-but-the-arrow-is-wavy-not-straight). As suggested in the accepted answer : I can use the `pict2e` package in normal cases but for `cancel` this is a documented issue with the solution being (as far as I get it), add the line `\@ifundefined{OriginalPictureCmds}{\let\OriginalPictureCmds\relax}{}` to my document preamble.

This results in an error and doesn't work out. The error is : `! You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode`.

Can someone please help me make this work so that the arrow is smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tikz`.

[image]

We define a new command `\cancelto` that takes three arguments, one optional. The first required argument is the "to" expression, which is `0` in the example. You could use `\scriptsize{0}` if you want it smaller. The second required argument is the expression that is to be cancelled. The calling sequence is

```
\cancelto[<height>]{<to>}{<expression>}
```

The optional argument adjusts the angle of the arrow by specifying the height above and below the cancelled expression. In the example it is set to `3ex`. I set the default to `.5ex`.

First the lengths `\hght` and `\wdth` capture the height and width of the expression using `\widthof` and `\heightof` (from the `calc` package). Then an arrow is drawn inside a box of 0 size (to overlap the expression). Then the expression is placed.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\hght}
\newlength{\wdth}

\newcommand{\cancelto}[3][.5ex]{\setlength{\hght}{\heightof{$#3$}}\setlength{\wdth}{\widthof{$#3$}}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[-latex](0,-#1)--(\wdth,\hght+#1) node[shift={(1mm,.5mm)}]{#2};}}#3}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{\frac{i}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{i-1}{2}}\cancelto[3ex]{0}{\{e^{it_1E_{i,i-1}}e^{it_2E_{i-1,i-2}}-e^{it_2E_{i,i-1}}e^{it_1E_{i-1,i-2}}\}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here the optional argument is set to its default, `.5ex`:

[image]

Of course, you can adjust the line thickness, color, arrowhead, etc. as you would anything you `\draw` with `tikz`.

Comment: I approve of your code and your ability. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, your kindness makes the world a better place.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answer. Can you point out the following as well? i) How did you know that `tikz` would do the trick? ii) Any way to do this without invoking any other package? I really want to get the same result with `cancel` package.

Comment: @Nitin, tikZ has become the standard for most graphics in LaTeX. Commands from the `picture` environment (`\put`, `\line`, `\vector`, `\circle`) can sometimes used for basic tasks, but their scope is limited. In particular, the `\line` and `\vector` commands only accept integers between -4 and 4 for slopes. The `cancel` package uses these commands and so can't really be fixed without a complete overhaul, which honestly would probably use tikZ.

Comment: If you're really opposed to using tikZ, you could use the ideas from this solution to create an arrow that has the appropriate length and then use `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package. But tikZ makes this much easier.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I thought that `cancel` was not using these commands. My main purpose to avoid `tikz` was to keep my preamble as short as possible. Anyways, I got it now. Thanks again. :)